# Digital and analog read from arduino on Labview

Tags: arduino, labview

I'm trying to visualize temperature and graphing voltage analog reading from arduino on Labview, however after some time the adquisition and the waveform chart slow down. I'm using a DS18B20 sensor this is my code on arduino:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#define Pin 2                      
OneWire ourWire(Pin);                
DallasTemperature sensors(&ourWire); 

void setup() {
delay(1000);
Serial.begin(9600);
sensors.begin();                    
}

void loop() {
sensors.requestTemperatures();       
int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);  
float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
Serial.println(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0)); 
Serial.print(",");
Serial.println(voltage);
delay(100);                        
}
```

NOTE: I'm sending the data fro arduino on the same line but separated by a coma[image]

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I make the waveform chart go faster?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can change to improve your performance, all in the red box below:

1. Move the [`VISA Configure Serial Port.vi`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361L-01/lvinstio/visa_configure_serial_port/) *outside* of the while loop. You only need to configure the port once after opening it, not for every read.
2. Tune the [read timeout](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/874B379E24C0A0D686256FCF007A6EA0).
3. Confirm your VI and Arduino program use the same [termination character](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/4256/en/).

Right now, your Arduino program sends **two** termination characters for every sensor read, but your VI expects there to be only one.

Each call to `Serial.println()` will send a [CRLF character sequence](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println):

```
Serial.println(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0)); // EOL here
Serial.print(",");
Serial.println(voltage);                    // EOL here
```

## VI Updates

[image]

Comment: I don't think the wait is needed here for reducing the cpu time. In the read from serial there is already a wait on the buffer.